# Automatically downloading a file with a name that's a function of the date

Tags: powershell, pdf, download, automation

How would I automatically download a file at a certain time of the day each day? The thing is, the file I have to download changes its name each day, e.g., file1706.pdf today and then file1806.pdf tomorrow and so on, with the name corresponding to the date. Hopefully there's an answer out there which does not require me to download any additional software.

Comment: What part(s) of this do you need help with?  Can you generate the *DDMM* string?  Can you download a file if you know its name?  Do you know how to schedule an action to occur automatically? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: `$fileName = "file{0:ddMM}.pdf" -f (Get-Date)` and `Invoke-WebRequest "https://site.tld/api/$fileName"`